# find top_k element of numpy ndarray and ignore zero

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, np.argsort

Given a numpy ndarray like the following

```
x = [[4.,0.,2.,0.,8.],
     [1.,3.,0.,9.,5.],
     [0.,0.,4.,0.,1.]]
```

I want to find the indices of the top k (e.g. k=3) elements of each row, excluding 0, if possible. If there are less than k positive elements, then just return their indices (in a sorted way).

The result should look like (a list of array)

```
res = [[4, 0, 2],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [2, 4]]
```

or just one flatten array

```
res = [4,0,2,3,4,2,2,4]
```

I know `argsort` can find the indices of top k elements in a sorted order. But I am not sure how to filter out the 0.

Comment: In your question instead of `3,4,2` should be `3,4,1` because `9` in index `3`, `5` in index `4`, and `3` in index `1` not `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort` with `(-num)` for getting index as descending. then use `numpy.take_along_axis` for getting values base index of 2D sorted.
Because you want to ignore `zero` you can insert zero for other columns after `three` *(as you mention in the question)*. At the end return value from the sorted values that is not zero.

```
x = np.array([[4.,0.,2.,0.,8.],[1.,3.,0.,9.,5.],[0.,0.,4.,0.,1.]])
idx_srt = np.argsort(-x)
val_srt = np.take_along_axis(x, idx_srt, axis=-1)
val_srt[:, 3:] = 0
res = idx_srt[val_srt!=0]
print(res)
```

---

```
[4 0 2 3 4 1 2 4]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! I also came up with a solution myself and it seems to be a little bit faster (np.argsort took the majority of time, as I am operating on a 100k x 100k matrix). I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these two:

```
k = 3

res = [sorted(range(len(r)), key=(lambda i: r[i]), reverse=True)[:min(k, len([n for n in r if n > 0]))] for r in x]
```

or

```
res1 = [np.argsort(r)[::-1][:min(k, len([n for n in r if n > 0]))] for r in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:

```
top_index = score.argsort(axis=1) # score here is my x
positive = (score > 0).sum(axis=1)
positive = np.minimum(positive, k) # top k

# broadcasting trick to get mask matrix that selects top k (k = min(2000, num of positive scores))
r = np.arange(score.shape[1])
mask = (positive[:,None] > r) 
top_index_flatten = top_index[:, ::-1][mask]
```

I compare my result with the one suggested by @I'mahdi and they are consistent.